# Glslang shader "header" file naming conventions

Tags: glsl, vulkan

For typical shader stages glslang enforces the naming conventions `*.vert`, `*.tesc`, `*.tese`, `*.geom`, `*.frag`, `*.comp` which let you compile your shaders to Spir-V without specifying the `-S` flag.

However what about "header" files with common functions that you may include inside many shaders for multiple different stages using the `GL_GOOGLE_include_directive` extension?

Obviously people are free to name them however they want but are there some reasonable conventions that have emerged?

Comment: I can't find an extension specification for that extension anywhere online. So I'm not sure how it could be widely used enough for "some reasonable conventions" to emerge.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas Thinking about it that way you're probably right. I'm not sure how commonly used it is. I couldn't find specification either. The way I learned about it was by trying  the `GL_ARB_shading_language_include` extension which didn't work  and then glslang spat an error message saying that it needs `GL_GOOGLE_include_directive` in order to use `#include` inside my shader.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [shaderc tests](https://github.com/google/shaderc/blob/master/glslc/test/include.py) for file inclusion use `.glsl` as the suffix for included files, while still using `.vert`, `.frag` etc. for the top-level file.